# How to identify that I method was called by a fragment?

Tags: android

I have an MainActivity that in turn has several fragments.

In the fragments builder I get an Activity ...

I have a GETJson method that is responsible for all my http requests. This needs to return a JSONObject to the caller.
The method uses AsynkTask, so I created an interface and implement the fragments to get the return from OnPostExecute.

However as all fragments share the same activity (MainActivity) always returns there.

```
package JSON;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.piadas.MainActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import utils.OnJsonFinished;

public class GetJson extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public interface OnJsonFinished{
        public void onJsonFinishedMethod(Activity act, Context ctx, String response);
    }

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context ctx;
    Activity act;
    String msg;
    private utils.OnJsonFinished listener;






    public GetJson(Context ctx, Activity act) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.act = act;


        if(act instanceof utils.OnJsonFinished){
            this.listener = (utils.OnJsonFinished)act;
        }
        else{
            throw new ClassCastException(act.toString()
                    + " must implement OnJsonFinished");
        }

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Aguarde", "Consultando...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String command = strings[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(command);
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic c3VwZXI6MTIzNA==");
            con.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            //con.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

            /*HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(command);
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 8000);
            client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic c3VwZXI6MTIzNA==");

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();*/

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            msg = "Efetuado com sucesso!";

            //PrincipalActivity.PDV.setConectado(true);
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Erro", "Descrição:", ex);
            msg = ex.toString();
            return "";
        }


    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        if (json.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            listener.onJsonFinishedMethod(act, ctx, json);
        }

    }


}

    package utils;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;

    public interface OnJsonFinished {

        public void onJsonFinishedMethod(Activity act, Context ctx, String response);
    }

package com.example.piadas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import JSON.GetJson;
import JSON.apiPiadas;
import adapter.adapterListPiadas;
import piadas.entidade.Categoria;
import piadas.entidade.FaixaEtaria;
import piadas.entidade.Piada;
import utils.OnJsonFinished;

public class BancoPiadaFragment extends Fragment implements OnJsonFinished {

    RadioGroup rgCategoria;
    RadioGroup rgFaixa;

    private View view;

    Button btnBuscar;

    EditText editPalavra;
    List<Piada> listaPiadas;
    ListView lvPiadas;

    Context ctx;
    Activity act;
    adapterListPiadas adapterPiadas;

    public BancoPiadaFragment(Activity act, Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.act = act;
    }



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bancopiada, container, false);

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initView();
        init();


    }

    private void initView(){
        btnBuscar = view.findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
        rgCategoria = view.findViewById(R.id.gpCateg);
        rgFaixa = view.findViewById(R.id.gpFaixas);
        editPalavra = view.findViewById(R.id.editPalavra);
        lvPiadas = view.findViewById(R.id.lvPiadas);
    }

    private void init(){

        btnBusca_click();
        //listaPiadas = new ArrayList<>();
        lvPiadas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, new PiadaFragment(listaPiadas.get(position))).addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

    }



    private void btnBusca_click(){
        btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listaPiadas = new ArrayList<>();
                aplicaFiltroPiadas();
            }
        });
    }




    private void aplicaFiltroPiadas(){
        //int i = rgCategoria.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        int categoria = -1;
        int faixaEtaria = -1;
        String palavra = "";

        switch (rgCategoria.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.rbTCategoria:
                categoria = -1;
                break;
            case R.id.rbJoaozinho:
                categoria = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.rbJapones:
                categoria = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.rbLoira:
                categoria = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.rbPortugues:
                categoria = 1;
                break;
        }

        switch (rgFaixa.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.rbTFaixas:
                faixaEtaria = -1;
                break;
            case R.id.rbFLivre:
                faixaEtaria = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.rbF14:
                faixaEtaria = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.rbF18:
                faixaEtaria = 2;
                break;

        }
        palavra = editPalavra.getText().toString().trim();

        findPiadas(categoria, faixaEtaria, palavra);



        //Toast.makeText(this, "Teste:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void findPiadas(int categoria, int faixa, String palavra){

        new GetJson(ctx, act).execute(apiPiadas.findPiada(categoria, faixa, palavra));

    }



    private void preparaTela(Activity act){
        adapterPiadas = new adapterListPiadas(listaPiadas, act);
        lvPiadas.setAdapter(adapterPiadas);
    }


    @Override
    public void onJsonFinishedMethod(Activity act, Context ctx, String response) {
        if (!response.equals("")) {
            try{
                JSONArray arrayPiadas = new JSONArray(response);
                JSONObject objPiada;
                for(int i=0; i < arrayPiadas.length(); i++){
                    objPiada = arrayPiadas.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject objCategoria = objPiada.getJSONObject("categoria");
                    JSONObject objFaixaEtaria = objPiada.getJSONObject("faixaEtaria");

                    Categoria cat = new Categoria(objCategoria.getInt("id"), objCategoria.getString("nome"));
                    FaixaEtaria faixaEtaria = new FaixaEtaria(objFaixaEtaria.getInt("id"), objFaixaEtaria.getString("descricao"));
                    listaPiadas.add(new Piada(objPiada.getInt("id"), objPiada.getString("titulo"), cat, faixaEtaria, objPiada.getString("conteudo"), objPiada.getString("imagem")));
                }
                preparaTela(act);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I need to identify which fragment called GETJson and return the String to it.

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger and find it out on your own?

Comment: I would think that's why you are passing in a callback, to return the results to the caller?

Comment: Can you tell me, In which class you are calling `GetJson ` . Let me know if there is any restriction to call it from Fragment. Also, AsyncTask has many disadvantages that it cannot listen to LifeCycle changes and soon will be deprecated. Consider moving towards Rx.

Comment: If you want to each fragment to get their own network callback, you SHOULD pass fragments to `GetJson` as listener, rather than Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to each fragment to get their own network callback, you SHOULD pass fragments to `GetJson` as listener, rather than Activity.
Modify `GetJson`'s constructor:

```
public GetJson(Activity act, OnJsonFinished listener) {
}
```

just use act as context, no need to pass both them.

In BancoPiadaFragment:

```
private void findPiadas(int categoria, int faixa, String palavra){
   new GetJson(act, this).execute(apiPiadas.findPiada(categoria, faixa, palavra));
}
```